# Why does second iteration always fail?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I am trying to create a dict of z_scores by filtering a dataframe based upon five locations.

No matter which location is first in the list, I always get the first key:value pair placed into
the dict, and no matter which location is second, I always get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\pydevd.py", line 1434, in _exec
    pydev_imports.execfile(file, globals, locals)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2018.2.1\plugins\python\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Mark/PycharmProjects/main/main.py", line 104, in <module>
    z_score = z_score(base, df['SalePrice'])
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

Since every list value works when it is first, I don't see why every subsequent iteration fails.

My code:

```
    def z_score(val, array, bessel=0):
        mean = array.mean()
        st_dev = std(array, ddof=bessel)
        distance = val - mean
        z = distance / st_dev

        return z


    neighborhoods = ['NAmes', 'CollgCr', 'OldTown', 'Edwards', 'Somerst']

    base = 200000
    z_scores = {}
    for neighborhood in neighborhoods:
        df = houses.loc[houses['Neighborhood'] == neighborhood]
        z_score = z_score(base, df['SalePrice'])
        z_scores[neighborhood] = z_score


    sorted_z_scores = sorted(z_scores.items(), key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
    print(sorted_z_scores)
```

Comment: try using a variable name that is not 'z_score`, python is confusing your floating point `z_score` and the method name `z_score`.

Comment: That was it.  Much obliged.

Comment: sounds good, I made it an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the interpreter puts a higher priority on your variable names in the local scope than method names, so when you use `z_score` as a variable name, it masks access to the `z_score` method name, if you change the name of your `z_score` variable, your code should run.